# Customizing twitter-bootstrap table. Header floats left

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

Currently I am working on table customziation for my project. I am using Twitter Bootstrap rails gem (2.2.6). However I think this should not be an issue when it comes to CSS customization.

So basically I want to achieve the following mockup:
[image]

However when I put radius border on  nothing happens unless I `float` it `left` or display it in block I don't see rounded borders. Please review the following jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/zaEFz/2/

But the issue is: when floating the content left, I loose the structure of the table. That means headers don't match content anymore. So few questions:

1. How to align the content with headers? If using float:left
2. How to round the corners for each row? If not using float:left and display:block

If you answer one of the questions that should be fine :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Sadly, `border-radius` doesn't work on `<tr>` tags -- only on `<th>` and `<td>` tags. But the style you need is very much achievable within those constraints.

#### CSS

```
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0 5px;
}

thead th {
  background-color: #006DCC;
  color: white;
}

tbody td {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
}

tr td:first-child,
tr th:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
}

tr td:last-child,
tr th:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zaEFz/4/)

[image]

**Update:** Fixed on Firefox, simplified selectors.

Comment: Fixed it. On Firefox, you need to apply the `background-color` to the same tag that receives the `border-radius`. It actually makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

To make things line up if you go for the float/block solution, I think you have to specify a fixed width for `<td>` and `<th>`:

```
th, td {
    width: 40px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

If you want different side padding for `<th>` and `<td>` you'd have to adjust the width accordingly so that the totals match.

If you leave the table layout alone, the solution seems to be to apply the border-radius to the first and last cell of the thead rather than to the tr. There may be other hacks required too to get things working. Please see [How-to create rounded corners on Table Head only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873936/how-to-create-rounded-corners-on-table-head-only) and [How can I have a rounded border on my table and border-collapse: collapse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889567/how-can-i-have-a-rounded-border-on-my-table-and-border-collapse-collapse) for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, however that does not solve the issue. First of all, I have more than 43 tables, and it will take around 4-5 weeks to adjust it accordingly in multiple browsers

Also, the solution can not be applied to only first and the last cell, please review the mockup

Comment: I mean first and last cell of every `<tr>` which you want to appear to have rounded corners. Is that not compatible with your mockup?

Comment: OK, I got it, but it's to way hacky :)

Comment: Well, I can't change reality. You wanted a solution and I found what seems to be the best one available, which is confirmed by mdepolli's anwer that uses the same approach.