# Round table corners

Tags: html, css, css-tables

Can you help me with making the table corners round? I've tried the simple `border-radius` but this just split the border in the corners. Is this caused by my browser (Firefox) or its a bug ? Jsfiddle  - http://jsfiddle.net/vuys8eef/

Comment: Your question can be answered here [Rounded Table Corners CSS Only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932181/rounded-table-corners-css-only)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rounded table corners CSS only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932181/rounded-table-corners-css-only)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to round corners for the first and last columns of your first and last row in your table.

Something like this:

```
table tr:first-child th:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}


table tr:first-child th:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

table tr:last-child td:first-child {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

table tr:last-child td:last-child {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

You can see your updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vuys8eef/2/)

Comment: prefixes for ``border-radius`` are not needed.

Comment: just looking out for you, no one has time for extra work xP

Comment: Thanks. This fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You were applying it to the wrong element, use this instead.

```
td, th{
   border-radius: 5px;
}
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/yYxqPM)

Answer (score 1):

Hello your code is fine but you could to use `overflow:hidden` on table to hide content inside. That's one way to do this :)

example [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SzymonDziewonski/4jpmefxv/)