# Round corners of table

Tags: html, css

I try to make round corners of my table

Here is  my code

```html
<table class="table" style="width: 100%;border-style: solid; border-color: #1d69b4;border-radius: 10px;">
  <tr style="background: white;">
    <th style="font-size: 18px; text-align: center;">
      <b>Hours</b><b style="margin-left: 30px;"> Monday</b>
    </th>
    <th style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center;">
      <b>Hours</b><b style="margin-left: 30px;"> Tuesday</b>
    </th>
    <th style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center;">
      <b>Hours</b><b style="margin-left: 30px;"> Wednesday</b>
    </th>
    <th style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center;">
      <b>Hours</b><b style="margin-left: 30px;">  Thursday</b>
    </th>
    <th style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center;">
      <b>Hours</b><b style="margin-left: 30px;">  Friday</b>
    </th>
    <th style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center;">
      <b>Hours</b><b style="margin-left: 30px;"> Saturday</b>
    </th>
    <th style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center;">
      <b>Hours</b><b style="margin-left: 30px;"> Sunday</b>
    </th>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="title" style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px;">
      <div style="margin-top: 10px;"><b class="blue-text">08.00</b></div>
      <div style="margin-top: 10px;"><b class="blue-text">09.00</b></div>
      <div style="margin-top: 10px;"><b class="blue-text">10.00</b></div>
      <div style="margin-top: 10px;"><b class="blue-text">11.00</b></div>
      <div style="margin-top: 10px;"><b class="blue-text">12.00</b></div>
      <div style="margin-top: 10px;"><b class="blue-text">13.00</b></div>
      <div style="margin-top: 10px;"><b class="blue-text">14.00</b></div>
      <div style="margin-top: 10px;"><b class="blue-text">15.00</b></div>
      <div style="margin-top: 10px;"><b class="blue-text">16.00</b></div>
      <div style="margin-top: 10px;"><b class="blue-text">17.00</b></div>
      <div style="margin-top: 10px;"><b class="blue-text">18.00</b></div>
      <div style="margin-top: 10px;"><b class="blue-text">19.00</b></div>
    </td>



  </tr>
</table>
```

But it not works.

Where is trouble?

How I can make it rounded?

**EDIT**

I added whole code oа View for full understanding of problem. I see border, but not with rounded corners

Comment: it does make it ?

Comment: That's because you added the `</table>` where OP forgot to write it ;) @SlimShady

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `border-collapse: separate;` for the CSS of **Table**.

Answer (score 1):

`</table>` was missing

```html
<table class="table" style="width: 100%;border-style: solid; border-color: #1d69b4;border-radius: 10px;">
  <tr style="background: white">

    <th style="font-size: 18px; text-align: center;color:#1d69b4;border-style: solid; border-color: #1d69b4;border-radius: 10px;">
      <b>Hours</b><b style="margin-left: 30px;"> Monday</b>
    </th>
    <th style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center;color:#1d69b4;border-style: solid; border-color: #1d69b4;border-radius: 10px;">
      <b>Hours</b><b style="margin-left: 30px;"> Tuesday</b>
    </th>
    <th style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center;color:#1d69b4;border-style: solid; border-color: #1d69b4;border-radius: 10px;">
      <b>Hours</b><b style="margin-left: 30px;"> Wednesday</b>
    </th>
    <th style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center;color:#1d69b4;border-style: solid; border-color: #1d69b4;border-radius: 10px;">
      <b>Hours</b><b style="margin-left: 30px;">  Thursday</b>
    </th>
    <th style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center;color:#1d69b4;border-style: solid; border-color: #1d69b4;border-radius: 10px;">
      <b>Hours</b><b style="margin-left: 30px;">  Friday</b>
    </th>
    <th style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center;color:#1d69b4;border-style: solid; border-color: #1d69b4;border-radius: 10px;">
      <b>Hours</b><b style="margin-left: 30px;"> Saturday</b>
    </th>
    <th style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center;color:#1d69b4;border-style: solid; border-color: #1d69b4;border-radius: 10px;">
      <b>Hours</b><b style="margin-left: 30px;"> Sunday</b>
    </th>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If it is still not working for you, post all code you are using. Maybe there is an overwrite somewhere.

Comment: I made a snippet of your code. When you run it, it works like a charm.

Comment: Yeah, but when I run it on my machine, not, IDK why.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to apply the border radius property to the outer table element, not the individual rows / columns

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932181/rounded-table-corners-css-only)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfect. Run code snippet if you want to.

```html
<table class="table" style="width: 100%;border-style: solid; border-color: #1d69b4;border-radius: 10px;">
  <tr style="background: white;">
    <th style="font-size: 18px; text-align: center;">
      <b>Hours</b><b style="margin-left: 30px;"> Monday</b>
    </th>
    <th style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center;">
      <b>Hours</b><b style="margin-left: 30px;"> Tuesday</b>
    </th>
    <th style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center;">
      <b>Hours</b><b style="margin-left: 30px;"> Wednesday</b>
    </th>
    <th style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center;">
      <b>Hours</b><b style="margin-left: 30px;">  Thursday</b>
    </th>
    <th style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center;">
      <b>Hours</b><b style="margin-left: 30px;">  Friday</b>
    </th>
    <th style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center;">
      <b>Hours</b><b style="margin-left: 30px;"> Saturday</b>
    </th>
    <th style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center;">
      <b>Hours</b><b style="margin-left: 30px;"> Sunday</b>
    </th>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="title" style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px;">
      <div style="margin-top: 10px;"><b class="blue-text">08.00</b></div>
      <div style="margin-top: 10px;"><b class="blue-text">09.00</b></div>
      <div style="margin-top: 10px;"><b class="blue-text">10.00</b></div>
      <div style="margin-top: 10px;"><b class="blue-text">11.00</b></div>
      <div style="margin-top: 10px;"><b class="blue-text">12.00</b></div>
      <div style="margin-top: 10px;"><b class="blue-text">13.00</b></div>
      <div style="margin-top: 10px;"><b class="blue-text">14.00</b></div>
      <div style="margin-top: 10px;"><b class="blue-text">15.00</b></div>
      <div style="margin-top: 10px;"><b class="blue-text">16.00</b></div>
      <div style="margin-top: 10px;"><b class="blue-text">17.00</b></div>
      <div style="margin-top: 10px;"><b class="blue-text">18.00</b></div>
      <div style="margin-top: 10px;"><b class="blue-text">19.00</b></div>
    </td>



  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yeah, I see this, but when I run it on my machine, it not works

Comment: Give me screenshot

Comment: And which browser do you use?

Comment: Try adding `border-collapse: collapse;` in the CSS of **table**

Comment: Or `border-collapse: separate;`

Comment: `border-collapse: separate` helps.

Comment: happy to hear. :)

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer to the question.