# create rounded alternative table css class

Tags: html, css

i want to create a class for  element that rounded around of table and alternative row color (gray and white). and first row as header style (negative) also last row as footer.

now I change left top of first row first cell to rounded, and first row last cell right top also rounded ...

this is not good solution. anyone can help me?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Can you show us some basic markup and the intended appearance you want to achieve?

Comment: You want this ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/4932321/8517929

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with current style your problem resolved:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    table#t01 td{
        padding:5px;
        border: 1px gray solid;
    }
    table#t01 tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #eee;
    }
    table#t01 tr:nth-child(odd) {
        background-color: #fff;
    }
    table#t01 tr:first-child td:first-child {
        border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    }
    table#t01 tr:first-child td:last-child {
        border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    }
    table#t01 tr:last-child td:first-child {
        border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    }
    table#t01 tr:last-child td:last-child {
        border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table id="t01" cellspacing="0" align="center">
<tr>
    <td>first row - first cell</td>
    <td>first row - second cell</td>
    <td>first row - third cell</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>second row - first cell</td>
    <td>second row - second cell</td>
    <td>second row - third cell</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>third row - first cell</td>
    <td>third row - second cell</td>
    <td>third row - third cell</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>forth row - first cell</td>
    <td>forth row - second cell</td>
    <td>forth row - third cell</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>fifth row - first cell</td>
    <td>fifth row - second cell</td>
    <td>fifth row - third cell</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```